# Using VBA to detect which decimal sign the computer is using

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to use VBA to detect which decimal sign is being used on the computer?

I have a macro script that adds a conditional formatting to an excel sheet. The problem is that the target computers might use both decimal signs. So I want to make the script work for all computers.

The code looks like this:

```
With range("D" & row)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotBetween, Formula1:="=1,01*$C$" & row, Formula2:="=0,99*$C$" & row
    .FormatConditions(1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
End With
```

Comment: could you post your final answer, how it got resolved. Appreciated..

Comment: How did you add format conditoins ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't actually know the `Formula`s in `FormatConditions` accept localized formulas. In other places you have a choice between `Formula` and `FormulaLocal`.

---

> **Please note:**
>   This part turned out to be oversimplified to the point of being wrong. Please refer to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32973462/11683) (which should really have been the accepted one) for how `Application.DecimalSeparator` and `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)` actually behave.

To simply answer the question, you can use `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)` or simply `Application.DecimalSeparator` to know the separator.

---

But for non-trivial formulas it might be easier to assign the invariant English-locale based formula to the `Formula` property of a hidden cell and then read `FormulaLocal` from that cell and use that for `FormatConditions`. Excel will do all the conversions for you.

Comment: Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) worked while Application.DecimalSeparator didn't. Shouldn't they do the same thing?

Comment: @WaiWong They aren't generally same but they are same by default. `International` tells you the actual information from locale and is read-only. `DecimalSeparator` allows you to assign any other character as a separator and use it with `UseSystemSeparators = False`.

Answer (score 29):

Regarding the answer above, it is important to know that `Application.DecimalSeparator` and `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)` do not behave the same way:

- `Application.DecimalSeparator` will ALWAYS output the decimal separator chosen in Excel options even when Excel is told to use System Separators (from Windows regional settings)
- `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)` will output whatever is the actual decimal separator used by Excel whether it comes from Windows settings (when `Application.UseSystemSeparators = True`) or from Excel options (when `Application.UseSystemSeparators = False`)

I therefore strongly recommend to always use `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)`.

Comment: I did not know it behaved that way when I posted my answer. This should be the accepted one.

Comment: To add to the information above, if you change your locale's separator to something else in the Windows regional settings, `Application.International()` will [continue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56920961/11683) to report the separator originally defined in the locale, not the one you've overridden it to.

Comment: @GSerg Yipes -- so both are wrong? To do this right you need to use both of them and Application.DecimalSeparator ?  What actually is the code fragment that works in all cases?

Comment: To add to the information above, if you need the **System Separator** (and not the actual decimal separator used by Excel) - e.g. for the CDbl() function - use the approach provided by Erik A's answer - i.e. use `Format(0, ".")`.

Answer (score 10):

For applications other than Excel, the solution in the accepted answer is not available.

Instead, you can use `Format` to retrieve the decimal separator: an unescaped dot in `Format` gets replaced by the current decimal separator.

```
DecimalSeparator = Format(0, ".")
```

You can also look up the decimal separator from the registry

```
DecimalSeparator = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKCU\Control Panel\International\sDecimal")
```

Comment: `Format(0, ".")` is the only answer who fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [DecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214274%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property.

`Application.DecimalSeparator` then returns the decimal separator defined by the locale that excel is being run with.

On a side note: It's advisable, even though it's possible, to not change this and instead leverage it to your needs.

Comment: No, this is wrong. The default setting is UseSystemSettings = true, and then Application.DecimalSeparator is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert a known number derived from a calculation to a known string and thenextract the separator. In this example, 1/2 evaluates to a three-character string "0.5" or "0,5". The Mid function extracts 1 character from positon 2 in the string.

```
Public Function DecimalSeparator() As String
    DecimalSeparator = Mid$(1 / 2, 2, 1)
End Function
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents here mixing the Excel answers here and the awesome registry trick from Erik A.; but I want to include Word in this game, because I use to automate Word/Outlook a lot:

```
Function CorrectDecimalSeparator() As String
Dim auxCorrectListSeparator As String
    If WordIsOpen Then
        CorrectDecimalSeparator= Word.Application.International(wdListSeparator)
    ElseIf ExcelIsOpen Then
        CorrectDecimalSeparator= Excel.Application.International(xlListSeparator)
    Else
        auxCorrectListSeparator = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKCU\Control Panel\International\sDecimal")
    End If
End Function
Function WordIsOpen() As Boolean
    Dim oWord As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    WordIsOpen = Not oWord Is Nothing
    Set oWord = Nothing
End Function
Function ExcelIsOpen() As Boolean
    Dim oExcel As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    ExcelIsOpen = Not oExcel Is Nothing
    Set oExcel = Nothing
End Function
```