# Excel macros handling numeric values differently on various computers

Tags: excel, vba

Recently I had to create macro for some calculation in a spreadsheet. Macro worked fine on some computers, but it failed on other computer, which I don't hace full time access to. All of them had the same version of Windows and Excel.

After some analysis I recognised, that problem occured in following cases:

- My computer accepted cell values as numeric, when their decimal
  points where coma separeted, other didn't. All of them had dot as
  decimal separator set in windows region settings.
- My computer accepted cell values with spaces inside (f.e.: '2 134 432,32') as numeric, other didn't.

I ended up writing workarounds that handled those cases, BUT! I need to know where this problem come from and how to avoid them in future. DO you have any experience and can share it with me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using VBA to detect which decimal sign the computer is using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652409/using-vba-to-detect-which-decimal-sign-the-computer-is-using)

Comment: *Control Panel >> Regional settings*   and *Excel >> Options >> Advanced >> Editing*