# Excel ignoring regional settings when exporting number as string in VB6

Tags: excel, vb6, internationalization

In an existing VB6 application I have a requirement to export some data grid to Excel. The data consists of double values which may contain also `<` or `>` characters so all values are actually stored as **string**. Nevertheless system regional settings are considered and decimal separator is manually set/replaced in all values.

Exporting is done with `Excel.Application` object from Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library. The exact values from the grid are populated to the Excel worksheet using `Range("...").Value = myArray()` statement. I fill myArray() manually from the grid.

When exporting values on *English (United States)* regional settings, everything works fine. On *German (Germany)* however, it looks as though the decimal separator is not respected and it is used as thousands separator. In the end, value "45,120" becomes value "45120".

Example application:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim xl As Excel.Application

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set xl = New Excel.Application

    xl.Visible = True
    xl.Workbooks.Add
    xl.Range("A1:A1").Value = "45,120"

ErrorHandler:
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Exported worksheet (German regional settings):

[image: Exported worksheet with incorrect value]

The funny things is, the cell format changed to Number, which never occurs on English regional settings i.e. stays in General format. Furthermore, this does not occur for values less than 1 i.e. 0,475.

It seems as though Excel is being smart and doing a conversion to number, but always with dot as decimal and comma as thousands separator. Should I always convert decimal separator back to dot before exporting or am I missing something here?

I use Excel Professional Plus 2010 .

Comment: Have you tried to control the decimal separator with `application.DecimalSeparator` before exporting? Maybe you could switch the decimal separator to what you need, depending where are you working (English, German).  Also, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652409/using-vba-to-detect-which-decimal-sign-the-computer-is-using). Maybe it can help you

Comment: Or you could simply add `'` infront of your number which will stop excel from doing any conversions on the string and just accept it as a text :) (I haven't tried this for your scenario but have used something like this in the past)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I tried using `Application.DecimalSeparator`, but it didn't help. When I changed it, it reflected in values displayed in cells, but not when Excel was doing conversion internally.
@Zac True, but customers will do some calculations afterwards, so it is not an option.