# CDec: international syntax for argument string with decimals

Tags: vba, regional-settings

My Excel is set in English for everything (formula, interface, guide).
My Windows is set with "," for decimal symbol and with "." for Digit grouping symbol in regional settings, as I live in Italy.

If I write this code:

```
    Dim v As Variant
    v = CDec("12345678901234567000,123456789")
    v = v + 50
```

result is displayed as "12345678901234567050,123456789" (Variant/Decimal) in Locals window. Same if I msgbox it.

If I use "." instead than ",", result is 12345678901234567000123456839.

In VBA, when writing numbers (in form of numbers, not strings), I must use the english syntax i.e. "." for decimal symbol.

I believe that that code of my example would run wrongly by a Windows with English regional settings.

How can I (modify it to) make it run correctly with any regional settings?

Comment: IIRC, VBA will always use `.` as a decimal separator.  Your code will only run incorrectly if you feed in strings when you should be feeding in decimals.  In the same way that VBA sees `#12/1/2000#` as the 1st of December.  This is why you need to validate your data source before using it.  It applies to all code in all systems. If it didn't work this way coding would be impossible as you would need to change it as soon as you encountered a different language setting

Comment: The cited code works correctly with my Italian Windows.  Feeding it as string not only works but it's also the only way to pass numbers more long/precise than Double or LongLong numbers to the CDec function, that is the case of my example.

Comment: @Gareth Numeric literals hardcoded in VBA code always use `.` as a decimal separator. The `##` date literals, being another flavour of hardcoded numbers, also follow the same notation regardless. But the `C*` conversion functions work with strings and with respect to the computer's locale, because they are intended for interaction with the user, so they expect the strings to be formatted according to the computer locale.

Comment: @6diegodiego9 That is a very good and nicely asked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `C*` conversion functions (`CInt`, `CLng`, `CStr` etc) are all designed to work in the current locale of the computer. They will use the current decimal separator, so you are correct in assuming that `CDec` will fail to correctly process a hardcoded `,` on a system with a different decimal dot.

On contrary, `Str` and `Val` always work with English separators, but they do not support `Decimal`.

---

So one option coming to mind is to obtain the decimal dot [at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20652409/11683):

```vb
Dim v As Variant
v = CDec("12345678901234567000" & Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) & "123456789")
```

It should be noted however that if `Application.UseSystemSeparators` is `False` and `Application.DecimalSeparator` has been changed, then `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)` will [return that changed separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32973462/11683), not the one coming from the computer locale. So do not use this method if you cannot guarantee that `UseSystemSeparators` is `True`.

---

Another option is to express the decimal position in the form of division by a power of ten, which is fine with the precise fixed-point `Decimal` data type:

```vb
Dim v As Variant
v = CDec("12345678901234567000123456789") / CDec("1000000000")
```

---

Yet another option is to have a custom "CDec" that explicitly works in a certain locale, and always hardcode the strings in that locale:

```vb
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VarDecFromStr Lib "OleAut32.dll" (ByVal strIn As LongPtr, ByVal lcid As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef pdecOut As Variant) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function VarDecFromStr Lib "OleAut32.dll" (ByVal strIn As Long, ByVal lcid As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef pdecOut As Variant) As Long
#End If

Private Const LOCALE_INVARIANT As Long = &H7F&
Private Const S_OK As Long = &H0

Public Function ParseDecimalFromEnUsString(ByVal s As String) As Variant
  Dim hr As Long

  hr = VarDecFromStr(StrPtr(s), LOCALE_INVARIANT, 0, ParseDecimalFromEnUsString)

  If hr <> S_OK Then
    Err.Raise 5, , "Cannot parse the string. Error " & Hex$(hr)
  End If
End Function
```

```
? ParseDecimalFromEnUsString("12345678901234567000.123456789")
12345678901234567000,123456789

? TypeName(ParseDecimalFromEnUsString("12345678901234567000.123456789"))
Decimal
```

*(For a version of this code with more control over [what the string is allowed to contain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/ns-oleauto-numparse#members), see [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56904359/3) of this answer. The parameter that receives `NUMPRS_STD` is the one to change.)*

Comment: Why don't you call [VarDecFromStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-vardecfromstr) instead of `VarParseNumFromStr`/`VarNumFromParseNum`?

Comment: @FlorentB. Because I overlooked it and because even if I did not, I would probably dismiss it on the basis that it returns a `DECIMAL`, not realizing that a `DECIMAL` is a member of the [`VARIANT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-tagvariant) top-level union so it's equivalent to a `VARIANT`.