# Replace periods with commas ends up with period deletion

Tags: excel, vba, replace

This is my first month with VBA and I've overcome so many obstacles and reduced walls of code with loops, made code pretty much uncrashable, even when user using macro doesn't know what he/she is doing, but I am stuck with this:

```
If i = 1 Or i = 2 Then
  Columns("F:F").Select
  Selection.Replace ".", ","
  Selection.NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End If
```

For some reason the result of replacement of:
438595.73402778 is this 43859573402778

I tried different variations from recording the macro to gradually simplifying the code and ended up with above. Always same result. What am I missing here?

The code is kind of complex, because I have to take data from 6 temporary workbooks into 4 sheets, secure it, depending on user login etc. It works great, but I thought, let's make it even better, because 3 out of those 6 qlikview workbooks have incorrect format in 1 of 4 time tracking columns.

It's kind of sad that I had to write my first post for such thing

Comment: If `.`is your decimal separator (windows region settings) all is fine as you have a number and can't insert a string `,`into that. Why are you doing this? Try Str(myNumber)

Comment: There is an option for the separator in Excel too (options-> extendend -> use systemsettings (or not)

Comment: So the result of this macro is a file for 100 people. Pretty much all of them have "," as decimal symbol. But most importantly, what feeds the data have "," as decimal symbol. There's mistake only in one out of many columns. I could ask for the fix in the source, but it takes ages and it's been like that for few years.

Comment: Is your source data actual numeric values or string data?

Comment: if you are asking about the content it's numeric only, so date and time. If you ask about format of the column it's string.

Comment: So you telling that your source data has the comma as a decimal delimiter, but only one column got a dot as decimal delimiter? And still your data is all numeric? Not possible afaik

Comment: @JvdV I am probably using sematics incorrectly. You are totally right. And btw the solution you posted, worked like a charm. I wanted to upvote you, but the post was deleted :(

Comment: @RyszardStegliński, just undeleted again.

Comment: Considered using a database like Sql Server?

Comment: To comprhend your error, you have dot as ds(dec-sep) and others have comma? How do you collect data from wbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your current data is actually string data looking like numeric values. If column F is formatted to `General` and these "string" numbers appear, then you could change that around using `Range.TextToColumns`. For example:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, rng As Range

With Sheet1

    'Get last used row of column F and set rng
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("F2:F" & lr)

    'Replace dot with comma and change to numeric
    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=","
    rng.NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong @computerversteher. Data is numeric in all columns but one. Source data pasted string data looking like numbers.

Comment: How could that happen? Excel sees data as number with wrong ds?

Comment: @computerversteher. Paste string data holding the dot into a General formatted cell.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but still confused on that ;)

Comment: @JvdV Ha! I couldn't upvote because I didnt have 15 points at that moment. Now you have what you surely deserve :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have different decimal separator settings in Excel files.

Go to Options-> extended-> use systems decimal separator.

This option may be off on some workbooks and `,`is set as decimal separator.

to fix:

```vb
If Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) = "," Then
    MsgBox "Wrong decimal separator(,)!!"
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = True
End If
```

If you want to output dot but leave comma the separator use

```vb
With ThisWorkBook.WorkSheet("Sheet1")
   MsgBox Str( .Range("A1"))
End With
```

See [Using VBA to detect which decimal sign the computer is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652409/using-vba-to-detect-which-decimal-sign-the-computer-is-using/32973462#32973462)

Comment: Only one column out of all columns with numeric data has a decimal point. This comes from the source, which by no means can be numeric while having comma in other columns. So this is not an is not an issue with system settings. It's string data looking like numeric values.