# Determine the unit setting in powerpoint

Tags: vba, methods, powerpoint, measurement

I am trying use VBA to determine the user preference for the measurement unit in PowerPoint, however, I can't find the correct method. Do you know a way to determine if the unit setting is in inches, cm, pt?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, there *is* no setting for preferred measurement units. PPT picks up the units, metric or imperial, from your Windows settings.

If it's important to know what units the user is seeing, you'd need to query the Win API.

If your code needs to use coordinates, the setting the user sees is not relevant; your code will use points (72 to the inch).

Did a bit of digging in a couple of Dan Appleman's old books and cobbled up this API call to determine whether the system is set to US or Metric. If I pass it 1033 (US English), it returns 1 until I go into Control Panel and set the system for metric; then it returns 0. But with the system set to US, the function returns 0 if I pass it the locale code for e.g. Dutch.

Fair warning: I'm strictly a cut/paste/play 'til it stops crashing API programmer. Nearly incompetent at it. Take it all with a grain of salt, eh?

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function GetLocaleInfo& Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal _
Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData _
As Long)

Function WindowsUSorMetric() As Long
' Returns 1 for U.S. or 0 for Metric
' NOTE: Needs modification before it'll work with 64-bit apps
'       Assumes USEnglish

    Dim Locale As Long
    Dim LCType As Long
    Dim lpLCData As String
    Dim cchData As Long
    
    ' 1033 is the languageID for US English
    ' Use the Object Browser in the VBA IDE, look up msolanguageid for others
    Locale = 1033
    LCType = &HD
    lpLCData = String$(255, 0)
    cchData = 255

    Call GetLocaleInfo(Locale, LCType, lpLCData, cchData)

    WindowsUSorMetric = CLng(Left$(lpLCData, InStr(lpLCData, Chr$(0)) - 1))

End Function

Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox WindowsUSorMetric
End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW, the situation is the same under macOS, the OS sets the measurement units, not the program. I'm not finding any obvious VBA Windows calls to measurement units, but you should be able to call Excel to get this info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlmeasurementunits

Comment: This explains a bit more:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/units-of-measurement.  Googling "vb locale_imeasure" (w/o the quotes) points to a few VB/VBA-usable examples, it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I had this need too; with Word or Excel is easy, because `Word.Application.Options.MeasurementUnit` or `Excel.Application.MeasurementUnit` returns it; but for other Office Apps you have to grab it from a registry key, if your project has no Word or Excel reference, of course.

I have in one module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const KeyInternationalMeasurementUnits As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\iMeasure"

Enum eMeasure
    Metrics = 0
    Imperial = 1
End Enum
Function eMeasure_ToEnum(str As String) As eMeasure
    Select Case str
        Case "Metrics": eMeasure_ToEnum = Metrics
        Case "Imperial": eMeasure_ToEnum = Imperial
    End Select
End Function
Function eMeasure_ToString(value As eMeasure) As String
    Select Case value
        Case Metrics: eMeasure_ToString = "Metrics"
        Case Imperial: eMeasure_ToString = "Imperial"
    End Select
End Function

Function RegKeyRead(ByVal ReadedKey As String) As String
    Dim thisWS As Object
    Set thisWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    
    RegKeyRead = thisWS.RegRead(ReadedKey)
    Set thisWS = Nothing
End Function

Function RegKeyExists(ByVal RegKey As String) As Boolean
Dim thisWS As Object

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Set thisWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  thisWS.RegRead RegKey
  RegKeyExists = True
  GoTo ExitFunction
ExitFunction:
  Set thisWS = Nothing
  Exit Function
  
ErrorHandler:
  RegKeyExists = False
  GoTo ExitFunction
End Function
```

And I call it whenever I need to:

```
Function WhichInternationalMeasurementUnits() As String
    If RegKeyExists(KeyInternationalMeasurementUnits) Then
        WhichInternationalMeasurementUnits = eMeasure_ToString(CInt(RegKeyRead(KeyInternationalMeasurementUnits)))
    End If
End Function
```

You can adapt too an IsWord or IsExcel precondition test like this one that I used to grab [which decimal sign is on regional settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59781048/2752308).