# Adding double variable to formula throws run-time error

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding a variable `Margin` to a formula, but it keeps generating an error. The readable formula is `=D17/(1-0.2)`.

The error is on the `Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/(1-" & Margin & ")"` part and the exact error is `run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`

```
Dim Margin As Double

Margin = 0.2

For i = 7 To lr1
    If Cells(i, "D").Value = "" Then
    Else
        Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/(1-" & Margin & ")"
    End If
Next i
```

When I split out Margin as 2 integers `Margin1` and `Margin2`, it runs fine.

```
Dim Margin1 As Double, Margin2 As Double

Margin1 = 0
Margin2 = 2

For i = 7 To lr1
    If Cells(i, "D").Value = "" Then
    Else
        Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/(1-" & Margin1 & "." & Margin2 & ")"
    End If
Next i
```

I'm assuming I'm defining the `Margin` value incorrectly? How can I get it work using 1 variable that contains a double value?

Comment: It can only be `=D17/(1-0.2)` since you're writing to column `E` with `C[-1]`. What is the exact error (number and description) and which line is highlighted?

Comment: @VBasic2008, correct it is D17 not E17. The error is on the `Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/(1-" & Margin & ")"` part and the exact error is `run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: I did some test, and I think it has something to do with your system separator. Are you using `,` comma as decimal separator?

Comment: @L42, yes `,` is our decimal separator for numbers - we use `;` in our formulas instead of `,`

Comment: so then try this `"=RC[-1]/(1-" & Replace(Format(Margin, "0.0"), ",", ".") & ")"`

Comment: This does the trick on my end when using system separators (`Options->Advanced`): `Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1Local = "=RC[-1]/(1-" & Margin & ")"`. Don't ask me why, I still can't believe that this should be necessary.

Comment: @L42, that did the trick! If you post it as an answer, I can accept. I think it's because we don't use QWERTY, but AZERTY (we've had more issues related to this in the past)

Comment: I won't post it because I don't know what's going on. Yet. When I switch to dot as the decimal separator (instead of the system separators) it only works with a string. It looks like VBA is converting to a comma too early. Hopefully, someone will know how to explain this issue. Give it some time.

Comment: Your code is reliant on behind the scenes VBA voodoo magic for coercion of numbers to strings.  Your first step in investigating this problem would be to replace implicit conversion of numbers to strings with explicit conversions using Cstr.

Comment: @freeflow When I write the formula to a string variable, then `Debug.Print` already shows the number with a comma, whether `CStr` was used or not.

Comment: The answer as to why your code behaves like this, and also why `FormulaR1C1Local` works are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20652409/2685412). It has something to do with how separators are handled in Excel. It seems, VBA always uses the `.` dot within VBA regardless of the system settings where in for your case `,` comma.

Comment: @VBasic2008, sorry I was referring to the OP code not yours.

Comment: @freeflow That might have come out wrong: I just wanted to share an observation to get closer  to the end of it.

Comment: OP  If you are not aware of it, installing the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA will likely help.  The code inspections help understanding of where implicit assumptions are being made about what VBA code actually does.

Comment: @freeflow, thanks i'll have a look into the Rubberduck addin