# VBA - Invalid procedure call or argument, Run time error 5

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA code for conditional formatting, but I keep getting this "Run-time error 5", Invalid procedure call or argument

```
Sub ApplyConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting")

    ' Define cell references for comparison values
    Dim current As Double, late As Double, target As Double
    current = ws.Range("K1").Value 
    late = ws.Range("K3").Value   
    target = ws.Range("K4").Value 

    ' Clear existing conditional formatting
    ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    ' Apply conditional formatting
    With ws
        
        .Range("L2:L" & ws.Rows.Count).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER(L2), L2<" & current & ", L2<>"""")"
        .Range("L2:L" & ws.Rows.Count).FormatConditions(.Range("L2:L" & ws.Rows.Count).FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    End With
    MsgBox "Conditional formatting applied"
End Sub
```

It's somewhere in the formula, but I am unable to figure it out.

**Edit**: If I use the following conditional formatting it seems to work but not when I add more check like in the above.

```
.Range("L:L").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:=current
```

Comment: Have you tried using `;` instead of `,`?

Comment: You could use `Dim Comma As String: Comma = Application.International(xlListSeparator)`. After you replace all commas with `" & Comma & "`, it should work for all languages.

Comment: Looks to me like it ought to work provided that "current" is a valid number. Which line does it fail on and what is the value of current at the time. If cell K1 doesn't contain a numeric value then all bets are off. BTW Factoring out .Range() into the "with" would improve readability. debug.print is your friend when things misbehave.

Comment: @MartinBrown, yes current is a valid number. Its failing on where I have the formula for conditional formatting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20652409/11683

Comment: I suggest debug.print "=AND(ISNUMBER(L2), L2<" & current & ", L2<>"""")" then and lets see what it is handing to Formula1 on your system. The code as written looks to me like it should work to me on a system where XL decimal point is "." and comma is ",". The other way to figure out where it is going wrong is to record a macro of setting these format conditions and compare its idea of the syntax to yours. It should generate legal macro code that you can test although it will use selection of range  and then "with selection. "  to do it. I'm with @VBasic2008 on this one.