# Use comma instead of dot for decimals when saving as text

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting

*This question looks similar to [Visual basic handle decimal comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215267/visual-basic-handle-decimal-comma), but that one is about an entirely different problem.*

I am writing a VBA macro to save my Excel file to a `.txt` file. This code line was generated by actually recording a macro where I saved the file to `.txt`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename, FileFormat:=xlText
```

Now, the issue is that the `.txt` file has all decimals formatted with dots, while I require them to be commas. For instance, it writes `32.7` while I am expecting `32,7`.

Some interesting details:

- I have made sure that Windows and Excel are setup to use the correct local settings. Everywhere I look, decimals are displayed correctly with commas.
- When manually saving the workbook, it correctly writes commas to the file as well. However, when executing the VBA code I recorded when doing this, I get dots.

Is there some nifty argument or option that I forgot? I am truly at a loss here -- even my fourth cup of coffee is not bringing any inspiration.

Comment: It's already there, @Bathsheba. This is really just a "save-as" with `xlText` as the file format. `Filename` is a string ending in `.txt`, but that should be of no importance.

Comment: Four cups of coffee is _never_ the threshold for inspiration. It will require at least seven, or one glass of Drambuie.

Comment: I would +10 that comment if I could, @paxdidablo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me (if your local separator is comma):

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename, FileFormat:=xlText, Local:=True
```

You can also specify any separator you want explicitly:

```
Application.DecimalSeparator = "," ' or any other separator, e.g. "-"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename, FileFormat:=xlText, Local:=True
```

but it affects entire workbook, you can then change it back after saving txt file, if it differs from your local separator

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm raising another cup to this one.