# VBA: CDbl ignores comma decimal separator

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro that copies specific cell values from a spreadsheet to another. The files are csv, semicolon separated, containing general formatted cells, including both literal items and numerical items. Numerical items have comma as decimal separator. The script imports properly everything, however, it ignores commas when importing the numerical values.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function importCsv2(strPath As String)
Dim filePath As String
filePath = strPath
Dim fileArray(5, 5) As String
Dim startDate As String
Dim Product As String
Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
If Range("B14").Value <> "" Then
    Range("B13").End(xlDown).offset(1, 0).Select
Else:
    Range("B13:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).offset(1, 0).Select
End If
currentRow = 0
rowNumber = 0

Open filePath For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, lineFromFile
    fileStr = Split(lineFromFile, vbLf)
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In fileStr
    'For item = LBound(fileStr) To UBound(fileStr)
        lineitems = Split(item, ";")
        'Debug.Print (item)
        If rowNumber = 1 Then
            startDate = lineitems(6)
            Product = lineitems(9)
        End If
        If rowNumber > 3 And item <> "" Then

            If Not doesOfferExist(CStr(lineitems(2))) And CInt(lineitems(0)) <> 0 Then
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 0) = startDate
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 1) = lineitems(4)
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 2) = lineitems(3)
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 3) = CDbl(lineitems(6))
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 4) = CDbl(lineitems(7))
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 5) = lineitems(8)
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 6) = lineitems(1)
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 7) = lineitems(2)
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 8) = "New"
                ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 9) = Product
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            End If
        End If


    Next item
    rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
Loop
Close #1

Call setImportLastUpdate
End Function
```

The critical part is:

```
ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 3) = CDbl(lineitems(6))
ActiveCell.offset(currentRow, 4) = CDbl(lineitems(7))
```

The excel options have comma set as decimal separator.

For instance, when importing 84,55 I get 8455 as a result.
I have added `Application.DecimalSeparator = ","` but it doesn't solve the problem.

Any help? thank you in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "it ignores commas when importing the numerical values". Do you mean the imported values are correct but displayed without the decimal separator? Or do you mean they are imported with incorrect values, e.g. the comma is being interpreted as a thousands separator?

Comment: It looks like you also have to set `ThousandsSeparator` and also set `Application.UseSystemSeparators = False` .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.DecimalSeparator

Comment: I also put an example...anyway, I repeat, from a value like 1,2 it imports 12. Everything else is correct: correct cell, correct splitting, correct numbers, etc. It is just the comma disappearing the problem.

Comment: Seems like the comma is being interpreted as a thousands separator

Comment: Not even, because from 1,2 I dont get 1200, but I get 12.

Comment: That's not how thousands separators work. They are used for display only but are ignored on input.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway.

Comment: OK look I've read your code now. CDbl doesn't care about Application.ThousandsSeparator or Application.DecimalSeparator. It just uses the system locale.

Comment: Since you are writing the import code just write your own ConvertDouble code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189653/discussion-between-ben-and-luca91).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual basic handle decimal comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215267/visual-basic-handle-decimal-comma)

Comment: Seems you are trying to re-invent the wheel. Either the legacy CSV import tool, or Power Query, have options to set the desired decimal and thousands separators when importing a CSV file.  Also look at the `QueryTables.Add` method

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but for future reference.

Set both the ***ThousandsSeparator*** and the ***DecimalSeparator*** like this:

```
Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Solved it by using the following helper function:

```
Function ConvertToDouble(s As String) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next ' Temporarily suppress errors for conversion
    Dim result As Double
    result = CDbl(s) ' Attempt to convert using locale-aware CDbl
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ConvertToDouble = "" ' Return empty string on failure
    Else
        ConvertToDouble = result ' Return the converted number
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Revert to default error handling
End Function
```